# Need help with Russian interjections, figures of speech

Tags: грамматика, перевод, выражения, сленг, междометие

I'm trying to find Russian equivalents for the following interjections/expressions:

- "Don't!" (when we very much don't want someone to do something)
- "No!" (to express dismay)
- "That's enough." (warning someone that they are about to cross the line)
- "You see..." (encouraging someone to listen & understand)

> **You see**, city guys like you aren't real welcome around here

Online translation tools are not very helpful with this sort of thing. Any input appreciated.

This question was closed earlier because I didn't provide evidence of prior research. I AM trying to learn Russian and am not trying to "cheat". I have completed a couple of extensive online Russian courses, but nothing in those courses covers this topic. I've also extensively researched Russian slang, but cannot find Russian equivalents for these interjections.

Two more that I'm having difficulty with:

- "now" (eg. *Now I'm not here to lecture you, only to tell you a story.*) I'm guessing that "сейчас" or "теперь" would not function the same way here.
- "I mean..." (eg. *What about notes? I mean, the scientist must have kept notes on his research.*). Would 'Я имею в виду' convey the same meaning here? To me it sounds too wordy.

Comment: As you know, we do not  translate words separately, but in a certain context. Would you mind at least provide sentences? Even in a sentence there might be variations.

Comment: "I mean..." - you can use the cognat - "я мню", "мню я", "мнится мне" :) This is somewhat archaic and funny a bit, but it's literally the cognate. This particular “мнится мне” have a some ironic connotation of uncertainty or ostentatious uncertainty. And of course - "я думаю", "думаю", "полагаю", "я полагаю".

Comment: " "now" (eg. Now I'm not here to lecture you, only to tell you a story.) I'm guessing that "сейчас" or "теперь" would not function the same way here." - "Сейчас" could be here. Why not. But not the "теперь" exactly here.  "теперь я тут не для того" is a crooked sentence, but it "теперь" can be use in "теперь я расскажу вам историю". 
Well, "так," . :)

Comment: "now" - also "итак" :)

Answer (score 2):

> **You see**, city guys like you aren't real welcome around here

This does not translate to a set expression. This could be *понимаешь* or *такое дело*

> Такое дело, городским типа тебя тут не особо рады.

---

> **Now** I'm not here to lecture you, only to tell you a story

This does not translate to a single set expression either. You could use *короче* or *в общем*, or just omit it altogether.

> В общем, морали я тебе читать не буду, а только расскажу случай из жизни.

---

> What about notes? **I mean**, the scientist must have kept notes on his research

In this context, this most probably would translate as *я к тому*.

> А что насчёт протоколов? Я к тому, что должен же был учёный вести протокол исследования.

Comment: "You see" can be "Видишь", "Now" isn't a "в общем"- it's not an 'at all" or "in general"... "Итак," will be better; 
 "I mean" isn't an "я к тому", stylistically at least...

Comment: In many (but not all) cases this "now" can be translated with "тут": "Я тут вам не собираюсь лекции читать". (Incidentally, this "тут" is not to translate "here" in this sentence).

Answer (score -2):

"Don't!" - "Cтой !", "Прекрати !", "Не надо !", "Нельзя!", "Стоп!",  any forbidding verb or ardverb...
https://youtu.be/eutO6SAA4Ys :> in this novell of Lem("The Inquest") this subject was the object of a court judicature... :>

---

"No!" (to express dismay) - Нет ! Не !... Не-не-не !
which "dismay" here ?

---

""That's enough."  - Хватит! Достаточно ! Остановитесь ! Прекрати ! Этого достаточно... этого хватит... с гаком хватит :>

---

"You see..."   - Ты видишь... Видишь... Видите - ...  Видити ли, ...
"As we see" - Как видно, Видно что, Как я вижу, Как мы видим,...
...

Comment: i think you have a mistake in the last example. "you see..." has nothing to do with the verb "смотреть" in this context. It should translate like "понимаете, понимаешь". I see = я понимаю (понял)

Comment: Dmitry, Я вижу ~= Я понимаю. 
"Видити ли" = Понимаете ли ?
" in this context." - which context for "You see" here, in your opinion ? At all, "see" = "видеть/смотреть' in any contexts... :>

Comment: TS mentions the value: "encouraging someone to listen & understand"

Comment: Dmitry, кароче, дело к ночи... "encouraging someone to listen & understand" - подобная эвфимистическая фраза и означает побуждение, подобное нашему мягкому побуждению к пониманию "Видишь... видите ли..."
Это не совсем то же, что "You must see"... если такое бывает, в любом случае у нас бывает - "ты должен видеть"... Но разница лишь в этой мягкости, но не в сути; видеть (ментально) тут и означает - понимать.
О чем вы толкуете тут ?

Comment: relax, just indicate the context. For me it is clear

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I have a clear idea now regarding the first three interjections. I didn't give a full sentence for those because those WERE the whole sentences. The fourth one, though (You see) I should've given the whole sentence: "You see, city guys like you aren't real welcome around here".

Comment: @ChrisCarr: thanks for providing the context for the fourth one, I've added it to the question. Could you please add the context for the first three ones? Something that "don't", "no!" etc. would follow. You don't use these expressions out of blue, they have to be reactions to something, and that's exactly what we mean by the context. Thank you!

Comment: ""You see..." as "an encouraging someone " exactly - also it can be an imperative like "Посмотри/те/м на...", "Взгляни/те/нем на ..."

Comment: @Quassnoi: 1) A guy runs inside a burning building; his girlfriend cries 'Don't!' 2) A scientist discovers someone broke into his lab and destroyed years of research, and cries 'No!' 3) Two guys are having an altercation in a public place; a cop comes up them and says 'That's enough.' Another expression (not listed above): 'Look' (eg. A reporter is harassing a celebrity, trying to interview them about a huge scandal; the celebrity replies 'Look, I've said all I'm going to.' I'm guessing this would translate as 'Понимаете' or 'Слушаете/Послушаете'?

Comment: @ChrisCarr: thanks! mind adding it to the question itself?

Comment: Chris Carr "... the celebrity replies 'Look, I've said all I'm going to.' I'm guessing this would translate as 'Понимаете' or 'Слушаете/Послушаете'?"  -not a "слушаЕте" or "послушаЕте" as future form of the verb, but "слушаЙте." or "послушаЙте.". The imperative;  And it can be "Видите ли, я сказал всё, что хотел сказать" too. :)

Comment: Chris Carr, "Look, i've said" - and you could to use "Посмотрите" (if you need) but in the idiomatical forms as "Посмотрите на эту ситуацию", 'Взгляните на эту ситуацию - ..."
_______
Just  one simple "Посмотрите/Взгляните, " will be sound a .. bit strange... :)

Comment: "Look,..." as " 'Понимаете" - at all, this case is the rhetorical question. :) "Понимаете ? : - я сказал всё..."
"Понимаете ли ?" :)